# Exclude rows with formulas from range in macro

Tags: vba, excel

I made a Data Entry Form that ads or updates rows in a datasheet. With this http://www.contextures.com/exceldataentryupdateform.html as the base. The form has 128 rows and 5 of those are vlookup formulas (row 12, 19, 30, 34, 36) that should be excluded when using the view record navigation buttons. Otherwise the formulas get deleted and replaced by a value, if you use the nav buttons.

But I really have no clue how to do this. I'm really new to VBA. This is my first project so all help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ViewLogDown()

    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim inputWks As Worksheet
    Dim rngA As Range

    Dim lRec As Long
    Dim lRecRow As Long
    Dim lLastRec As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
    Set historyWks = Worksheets("Werknemers")
    Set rngA = ActiveCell

    With historyWks
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row - 1
        lLastRec = lastRow - 1
    End With

    With inputWks
        lRec = .Range("CurrRec").Value
        If lRec < lLastRec Then
            .Range("CurrRec").Value = lRec + 1
            lRec = .Range("CurrRec").Value
            lRecRow = lRec + 1
        historyWks.Range(historyWks.Cells(lRecRow, 3), historyWks.Cells(lRecRow, 128)).Copy
        .Range("D5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        inputWks.Range("OrderSel").Value = .Range("D5").Value
        rngA.Select
          End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy and paste and exclude formula-based cells then you can use the [`SpecialCells`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method of the `Range` object. `xlCellTypeConstants' will filter out cells without a formula *and* blank cells.

E.g. with your code:

```
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngFilter As Range

Set rngSource = historyWks.Range(historyWks.Cells(lRecRow, 3), historyWks.Cells(lRecRow, 128))
Set rngFilter = rngSource.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
```

Note once pasted the `Range` will be smaller than the original because the cells with formulas are discounted.

You can `Union` different calls `SpecialCells` together. So to include blanks you could use:

```
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngFilter As Range

Set rngSource = historyWks.Range(historyWks.Cells(lRecRow, 3), historyWks.Cells(lRecRow, 128))

Set rngFilter = Union( _
    rngSource.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), _
    rngSource.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) _
)
```

Sample code for minimal example of use of `SpecialCells`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestRangeCopyExcludingFormulas()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngToCopy As Range
    Dim rngToCopyExcludingFormulas As Range
    Dim rngToPaste As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range

    ' set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' set the range to copy excluding formulas
    Set rngToCopy = ws.Range("B3:B13")

    ' copy just the constants
'    Set rngToCopyExcludingFormulas = rngToCopy.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    ' copy constants and blanks
    Set rngToCopyExcludingFormulas = Union( _
        rngToCopy.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), _
        rngToCopy.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))

    ' set the range to paste to
    Set rngToPaste = ws.Range("E3")

    ' do the copy and paste
    rngToCopyExcludingFormulas.Copy
    rngToPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ' use transpose etc
'    rngToPaste.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

    ' remove the dancing ants
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Great i think this is what i need but can you place also show me how to embed this in my code? because i tried pasting it in but it gives me a error.

Comment: The list i would like to end up with should look like this. In you bottom example they shift up. that would scramble the data.



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijYVP.png

Comment: the formulas in the pict should use collum A not B

Comment: The code won't copy and paste. You need to try and adapt the method to your situation. HTH